# Limitar la seleccion de elementos a solo uno abap alv

Tags: abap

Estoy haciendo un reporte ALV en abap y necesito que solamente se pueda tildar el checkbox de una fila sola, alguna sugerencia de como lograrlo?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.